# CUDA 8.0, GTX 1080, why is vector addition slower than matrix multiplication by 5x?

Tags: cuda, gpu

I am using latest CUDA 8.0 with GTX 1080, and running samples to test speed. (I know they do not reflect the optimal speed, but I just want to compare horizontally.)

In `0_Simple/matrixMul`, the speed is measured by the code, which gives:

```
Performance= 1029.91 GFlop/s, Time= 0.127 msec, Size= 131072000 Ops, WorkgroupSize= 1024 threads/block
```

Then I ran `0_Simple/vectorAdd`, and copy the speed testing code from above sample. i.e.:

```
// Measure speed
    cudaEvent_t start;
    cudaEventCreate(&start);
    cudaEvent_t stop;
    cudaEventCreate(&stop);

    cudaEventRecord(start, NULL);
    int nIter = 300;
    for (int i = 0; i < nIter; i++) {
        vectorAdd<<<blocksPerGrid, threadsPerBlock>>>(d_A, d_B, d_C, numElements);
    }
    cudaEventRecord(stop, NULL);

    cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
    float msecTotal = 0.0f;
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&msecTotal, start, stop);
    float msecPerAdd = msecTotal / nIter;
    double flopsPerAdd = numElements;
    double gigaFlops = (flopsPerAdd * 1.0e-9f) / (msecPerAdd / 1000.0f);
    printf("Performance= %.2f GFLOPS, Time= %.3f ms, Size= %.0f Ops\n", gigaFlops, msecPerAdd, flopsPerAdd);
```

I also enlarged the `numElements` from `50000` to `67108864`. The speed result is:

```
Performance= 19.85 GFLOPS, Time= 3.380 ms, Size= 67108864 Ops
```

which is almost 5x slower.

I know that sample code may be suboptimal, so could anyone tell me why the vectorAdd code is so slow, and how to optimize it?

I am using CUDA 8.0, and GTX 1080

Comment: what number is `numElements`?

Comment: @kangshiyin, I said in the post, it is 67108864, which is 64M.

Comment: can you show the code of your vectorAdd kernel ? And did you compiled with optimisation enabled?

Comment: @X3liF, the code is the sample code along with installing Cuda, and I used the Makefile provided by the sample... Do you have access to the sample?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike matrix multiplication, vector addition is a memory bandwidth bound operation. The correct way to measure its performance is to measure the bandwidth of the global memory access. For vector addition, it includes 2 input and 1 output vectors, and can be calculated as follows.

```
3 * numElements * sizeof(d_A[0]) / kernel_running_time
```

You could compare it with the bandwidth of a simple D2D copy to see if you have reached the peak.

Answer (score -1):

Edit: added code for GPU and CPU

I run the following experiment

***Cuda kernel

```
__global__ void add(float *a, float *c , size_t N)
{
  int tid = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;    
  if(tid < N) a[tid] += c[tid];
}
```

***CPU naive version (baseline)

```
void naiveAdd(float *h_a, float *h_c, size_t N)
{
   for (size_t i=0; i<N; i++)
      h_a[i] += h_c[i];
}
```

for performance comparison of adding two vectors in the same machine (740M GPU, 4th gen i7) with different CUDA GCC versions.

On CUDA 8.0 and GCC 5 the GPU versions were slower
[image]

On CUDA 7.5 and GCC 4.8 the GPU versions were faster 
[image]

With this evidence, I can conclude that it is better to avoid CUDA 8.0 for the moment.

Comment: It is unclear what and how you measured. Consider adding the complete code showing that, as well as the nvcc command used to build the code, and raw data from the runs (showing elapsed times rather than speedup).

Comment: i have related issue using Visual Studio. Same code compiled with CUDA Toolkit 7.5+VS2013 about twice faster than CUDA Toolkit 8+VS2015.